# Authentication localhost failed, in spite of ssh-keys

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, continuous-integration, github-actions, nohup

I'm setting up my virtual machine in CI such that I can tests a script that uses ssh.

I'm setting up my virtual machine running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
ssh-keygen -t rsa -q -f "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" -N ""
cat "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" >> "$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

(According to the docs the ssh-server is automatically started, and I verified that this is indeed the case using `sudo systemctl status ssh`)

To debug I ran

```
ssh -v localhost "uname -r"
```

giving:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'runner'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:NFnWPH2boToKCX0yq1K33LY0K3EwK810f599LpwoXJI
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
```

For completeness

```
cat /var/log/auth.log
```

gives:

```
Mar 10 06:13:08 fv-az189-848 php8.0: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Mar 10 06:13:09 fv-az189-848 php8.0: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Mar 10 06:13:09 fv-az189-848 php8.0: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Mar 10 06:13:52 fv-az189-848 sudo:   runner : TTY=unknown ; *** ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get install openssh-server
Mar 10 06:13:52 fv-az189-848 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 10 06:13:55 fv-az189-848 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 10 06:13:55 fv-az189-848 sudo:   runner : TTY=unknown ; *** ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status ssh
Mar 10 06:13:55 fv-az189-848 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 10 06:13:55 fv-az189-848 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 10 06:13:55 fv-az189-848 sshd[1847]: Connection closed by ::1 port 54242 [preauth]
```

It seems to me that ssh is finding the key alright, but is trying to read a passphrase that I set to be empty using the `-N ""` option here:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -q -f "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" -N ""
```

Therefore, I don't know how to resolve this issue. I could create `/dev/tty` but it seems to me that ssh should not even look for it.

Comment: `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `sshd_config` would reveal more info. Also check if `StrictMode` is not the problem.

Comment: @JiriB Thanks. But how do I actually set it? I tried `sudo echo "LogLevel DEBUG3" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but when I `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config` my setting simply does not seem to there??

Comment: `echo "LogLevel DEBUG3" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, the `>>` redirect is executed without root privileges in your case

Comment: Check if `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` contains correct data, perhaps you destroyed it somewhere while testing

Comment: @jeb Your tip to add the debug level works, but the output does not get any more useful. Also I checked `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` are identical. So, the mystery continues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your setting and it works for me.

But my debug output looks different after the `Server host key`

```
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:NFnWPH2boToKCX0yq1K33LY0K3EwK810f599LpwoXJI
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:15
```

I assume, that `localhost` isn't present in your `.ssh/known_host` file, therefore `ssh` wants to ask you for your confirmation.

You could try to start without checking

```
ssh -v localhost "uname -r" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

But the underlying problem is your missing `/dev/tty`, your current tty seems to be wrong configured in some way

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since the ssh commands I try to test are a bit nested I used `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new" -v localhost "uname -r"`. But... still ssh is not accepting my rsa key. It says `Offering public key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa RSA ...` but then it simply goes on to try the non-existing other key options and finally the password.  For reference, the complete setup and output are here https://github.com/tdegeus/shelephant/pull/81

Comment: Indeed I guess that `/dev/tty` is unconfigured on this virtual machine. However, I would assume that ssh should not even try to look that if the key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is matched. And the point (above) is that it simply doesn't match it

Comment: Since this was the answer to my question I accepted, and opened a second question that addresses the appearing problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/66563516/2646505